How can I create a multidimensional array or object from an HTML element tree?
I have this situation where I need to create a multi-dimensional javascript / jQuery array or object from available html div containers.
Each div element has a class named indexed, an ID, and an attribute called data-id such as following example:


jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {

        var obj = {}

        var count = 0;

        function extract_children( parent ){

            parent.find( '.indexed-' + parent.attr( 'id' ) + '-children > .indexed' ).each( function() {

                // need to build the object here and and return it

                console.log( $( this ).attr( 'id' ) );
                console.log( $( this ).attr( 'data-id' ) );

                var next = $( '.indexed-' + $( this ).attr( 'id' ) + '-children > .indexed' );

                if( next && next.hasClass( 'indexed') ) extract_children( $( this ) );

            });

        }

        $( '.indexedcontainer > .indexed' ).each( function(){

            count++;
      
            obj[ count ] = {};  
 
            obj[ count ][ 'id' ]        =  $( this ).attr( 'id') ;
            obj[ count ][ 'data-id' ]   =  $( this ).attr( 'data-id');
            obj[ count ][ 'children' ]  =  extract_children( $( this ) );



        }).promise().done( function(){

            console.log( obj );

        });

    }); 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="indexedcontainer">

    <div class="indexed" id="1" data-id="1000">
        <div class="indexed-1-children">
           <div class="indexed" id="101" data-id="1001">

                <div class="indexed-101-children">

                    <div class="indexed" id="102" data-id="1002">
                        
                        <div class="indexed-102-children">

                            <div class="indexed" id="1022" data-id="10022">
                                
                                there can be more such recurrence

                            </div>

                            <div class="indexed" id="1023" data-id="10023">
                                
                                there can be more such recurrence

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="indexed" id="102" data-id="1002">

                <div class="indexed-102-children">

                    <div class="indexed" id="1022" data-id="10022">

                        there can be more such recurrence

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

    </div>

</div>



there can be more than one first level div elements like
<div class="indexed" id="2" data-id="2000">...</div>
<div class="indexed" id="3" data-id="3000">...</div>

desired array or object required
obj[ 1 ][ id ] = 1;
obj[ 1 ][ data_id ] = 1000;

obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ id ] = 101;
obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ data_id ] = 1001;

obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ id ] = 102;
obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ data_id ] = 1002;
obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ id ] = ...


obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ children ][ 2 ][ id ] = 103;
obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ children ][ 2 ][ data_id ] = 1003;
obj[ 1 ][ children ][ 1 ][ children ][ 2 ][ children ][ 1 ][ id ] = ...





Off topic: count++; - I suggest you add this at the end so that your indexes are the standard (for javascript) 0-based.

Not clear what you are trying to accomplish. It was not clear how you wanted to get the data and add it all to the same object correctly. This is close, I think.


jQuery(function($) {
  var obj = {};

  function extract_children(parent) {
    var $p = $(parent);
    var $c = [];
    $('.indexed-' + $p.attr('id') + '-children > .indexed', $p).each(function(i, el) {
      console.log(i, $(el).attr('id'), $(el).attr('data-id'));
      if ($("[class$='-children']", el).length) {
        console.log("Nested Child Found.");
        $c.push($(el).attr("id"));
        extract_children(el);
      } else {
        $c.push($(el).attr("id"));
      }
    });
    return $c;
  }

  $('.indexed', '.indexedcontainer').each(function(i, el) {
    obj[(i + 1)] = {
      id: $(el).attr('id'),
      "data-id": $(el).attr('data-id'),
      children: extract_children($(el))
    };
  });
  console.log(obj);

});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="indexedcontainer">
  <div class="indexed" id="1" data-id="1000">
    <div class="indexed-1-children">
      <div class="indexed" id="101" data-id="1001">
        <div class="indexed-101-children">
          <div class="indexed" id="102" data-id="1002">
            <div class="indexed-102-children">
              <div class="indexed" id="1022" data-id="10022">there can be more such recurrence</div>
              <div class="indexed" id="1023" data-id="10023">there can be more such recurrence</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="indexed" id="102" data-id="1002">
        <div class="indexed-102-children">
          <div class="indexed" id="1022" data-id="10022">there can be more such recurrence</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



UPDATE
I did a lot of testing with your suggestions. What I determined is that your desired data structure is too complex for a recursive solution. Each time you loop, the nature of the code is just replacing the top level with the child.
To build the structure you are looking for, I suggest crawling each element, seeking children, and then repeating that for a number of levels.

if you change $('.indexed', '.indexedcontainer') to $( '.indexedcontainer > .indexed') then you will see the object returns one first level object that part is all right but then the children needs to have nested array ids and children arrays not the html contents.
